# Using Android Window Animations in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that I'm working with which has scrollable tabs in it. I have a button on one of the fragments which opens a sub activity. I want to use the translate animation that Android offers but it's giving me errors.

Button onClickListener code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SubActivity.class);

        Bundle translateBundle = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getActivity(),
        R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left).toBundle();

        startActivity(intent, translateBundle);
    }
});
```

Android Studio is giving me this error:

`startActivity (Intent) in Fragment cannot be applied to (Intent, android.os.Bundle)`

I tried searching S.O. for something like this but didn't find anything.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited Answer Try this!!

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SubActivity.class);

    startActivity(intent)

   getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left)
```

Comment: OK! The beginning transition works but when I press the back button and/or the up button it just displays the normal animation. Should I do something like the override in the main fragment too?

Comment: OK. Says to wait 3 minutes :)

Comment: @sandy This is a workaround, but doesn't address the underlying problem which is that `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` doesn't support `startActivity(Intent, Bundle)`.

Answer (score 1):

You're receiving that error because you're using the support library `Fragment` which doesn't have a wrapper for `Context.startActivity(Intent intent, Bundle options)`.

Instead you could pass your `Bundle` using `getActivity.startActivity(Intent, Bundle)`:

```
getActivity().startActivity(intent, translateBundle);
```

Alternatively, you could use `ActivityCompat.startActivity(Activity, Intent, Bundle`.

Comment: I seem to have made everything work now but I much appreciate your answer. Thanks!